# How can we exclude certain controls from getting focus?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, list, actionscript, itemrenderer

In my application, I have a List that uses an item renderer.

The renderer has two controls inside a Grid. I want the user to be able to tab through the TextAreas. However, I noticed that I need to tab twice to move to the next TextArea. I think it may be tabbing to the Label. How do I exclude the Label from the tabbing?

The code is below:

```
    <mx:HBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
     height="100%"
     implements="mx.controls.listClasses.IDropInListItemRenderer"
     width="100%">
        <mx:GridItem height="100%"
                     colSpan="5"
                     width="100%">
            <mx:VBox width="100%">
                <mx:TextArea id="txtFeedback"
                             tabIndex="0"
                             wordWrap="true"
                             maxChars="4000"
                             fontWeight="bold"
                             width="100%"/>
                <mx:Label fontSize="8" text="Thanks"/>
            </mx:VBox>
        </mx:GridItem>
    </mx:GridRow>
</mx:Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To exclude component from tab order set [tabEnabled](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#tabEnabled) property to false

Comment: Use this with the related [tabChildren](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#tabChildren) property too - this helps if you want the parent component to receive focus but not the children.

Answer (score 1):

Just tell the focus to keep on keepin' on when it gets to the label:

```
<mx:Label fontSize="8" text="Thanks"
    focusIn="{focusManager.moveFocus(mx.events.FocusRequestDirection.FORWARD)}"/>
```

Make sense?  :)